# How would add multiple logins to this python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Hey could you help me with this. I would like to add multiple logins to this script, with each login running separate code. For example if you entered

Username: xyz

Password: zyz

It would run A Script saying

```
# file-input.py
f = open('helloworld.txt','r')
message = f.read()
print(message)
f.close()
```

And then if you entered

Username: abc

Password: cba

It would Run this script

```
'''Illustrate input and print.'''

applicant = input("Enter the applicant's name: ")
interviewer = input("Enter the interviewer's name: ")
time = input("Enter the appointment time: ")
print(interviewer, "will interview", applicant, "at", time)

# file-output.py
f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
f.write(interviewer)
f.write(" will Interview ")
f.write( applicant)
f.write(" at ")
f.write( time)
f.close()
```

Anyway here's the full code:

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    username = "abc"
    password = "cba"

    username_entry = Entry(root)
    username_entry.pack()

    password_entry = Entry(root, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()

    def trylogin():
        if username == username_entry.get() and password == password_entry.get():
            '''Illustrate input and print.'''

            applicant = input("Enter the applicant's name: ")
            interviewer = input("Enter the interviewer's name: ")
            time = input("Enter the appointment time: ")
            print(interviewer, "will interview", applicant, "at", time)

            # file-output.py
            f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
            f.write(interviewer)
            f.write(" will Interview ")
            f.write( applicant)
            f.write(" at ")
            f.write( time)
            f.close()

        else:
            print("Wrong")

    button = Button(root, text="Enter", command = trylogin) 
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks For helping

Comment: I mean, you just need to add an elif to your login function to check for the other username and run the desired code, right?

Comment: When you want any number of any complex objects the best practice is almost (if not truly) always creating a class using OOP concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when writing apps with GUI's, in my opinion it is much easier and more efficient to use an Object orientated approach. 
For more details on how to implement tkinter applications using OOP please check out my guy Sentdex:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjNHATw6XgY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk

The code below takes userinputs and checks against the details we have set. If a ceratin username and password are enetered then it will run a certain function. At the moment i have only coded for one outcome, which is if the user enter "abc" ...

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)

        self.grid()

        self.username1 = "abc"
        self.password1 = "cba"

        username_label = Label(self, text="Username:")
        username_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        password_label = Label(self, text="Password:")
        password_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.username_entry = Entry(self)
        self.username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.password_entry = Entry(self, show='*')
        self.password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        login = Button(self, text="Login", command= self.tryLogin)

        def tryLogin(self):
            usernameInput = self.username_entry.get()
            passwordInput = self.password_entry.get()

            if usernameInput == self.username1 and passwordInput == self.password1:
                self.function1()

            else:
                print("wrong")
 # you can add elif username and password equals something else here but i 
 #suggest using my alternative method explained below using a database.

        def function1(self):
            print("executing function 1")



window = tk.Tk()
app = Application(window)
window.mainloop()
```

**HOWEVER** In my opinion the best way to execute what you are trying to do is to create a databse for your accounts. In thats database you should by default add the accounts with the function that they will execute.

For instance:

create a database (use sqlite3) with fields username, password, function

[image: using your example:]

Then when a user logins in, you can query the database. If the user enters login details which exist then return the functionName for that respective account and execute it.

*check this link out on how to create a login function and database:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBRzFm0BKuhaQyJ37KiI9rg3R3CC6-v9e

I would show you how to do this but you have to do some research now i have pinpointed you to 2 of the best guys and they cover how to do all these things.

Good luck m8!

Comment: Or like Aaron suggested you can just add a elif username and password = to my code. But if you have multiple logins this would be very inefficient. as you have to declare the details for each account in your python script as well as a bunch of long elif statements.